# SSRS Matrix Tablix with Trend Chart in One Column And Stacked Bar Chart in Another Column

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, charts

I need to combine a trend chart onto one column of a matrix and a stacked bar chart into another column – similar to this.  I have a label that runs over the top, which is why I don’t want to do two separate matrixes side by side.

[image]

Right now I have two different datasets for each.

[image]

If it was a roll up bar chart – I could just join the data sets and use aggregations for the bar chart – but with the stacked bar chart the issue of nominal values is tripping me up.

Answer (score 0):

Sorta figured it out.

The key was to make the stacked bar chart a subreport.  Then in the SQL for the dataset, add a WHERE Label = [Label passed in from Matrix row]